# SAGA 2.2.5 Problem Object Based Image Segmentation

Tags: saga, classification, landsat-8, land-classification, image-segmentation

Every time I use the Object Based Image Segmentation with Landsat 8 data I get a segmentated image which looks like a spider's web. The image contains no 0 values. Anyone has a idea how to fix this?[image: SAGA segmentation output]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because of the extent mismatch --- the extent of raster is larger than your area of interest. In the posted image, white outboard area is filled with NoData cells.

SAGA has a **Crop to Data** tool to fix it, by cutting NoData margins off and fitting the layer extent. In SAGA GUI - *Tools* pane, it is located under `Grid | Tools`. (From the menu `Geoprocessing | Grid | Grid system`).